# Python (pandas) Trying to make new column that combines two columns into one depending on values

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3 using pandas

I have a column with yearly, monthly, weekly.  I have another with compensation that is adjusted for those values.  I am trying to create a new column that keeps the yearly value if it is yearly, multiplies by 12 if it is monthly, multiplies by 52 if it is weekly.  I found elsewhere that I could maybe set a default like below but it is not working.

```
df['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'] = df['CompTotal']
df['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'][df['CompFreq'] == "Monthly"] = df['CompTotal']*12
df['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'][df['CompFreq'] == "Weekly"] = df['CompTotal']*52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [df['CompFreq'] == 'Monthly', df['CompFreq'] == 'Weekly']
choices = [df['Comptotal'] * 12, df['Comptotal'] * 52]

df['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df['Comptotal'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.select` is the best answer, buy you can also use `where` and do this:

```
import numpy as np
df['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'] = df[CompTotal]
df['NormalizedAnnualCompensation'] = np.where(df['CompFreq']=='Monthly', df[Comptotal]*12,np.where(df['CompFreq'] == 'Weekly', df[Comptotal]*52,df[Comptotal])
```